# How to avoid unknown values which are added to arraylist?

Tags: powershell, arraylist

I have added Arraylist as below

```
$queue = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()    
$queue.Add("Object1")
$queue.Add("Object2")
foreach ($i in $queue){
    $i
}
```

I thought the result will be displaying

```
Object1
Object2
```

But it displays as below

```
0
1
Object1
Object2
```

I don't know how 0 and 1 is added. How to get the values alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two numbers you see are the **indexes of the added items.** Thats because the `Add` method is returning the index of the added object, so just **pipe the result to `$null`**:

```
... 
$queue.Add("Object1") | out-null
```